# When I execute nlp.begin_training() I'm getting following error

Tags: spacy

"I'm trying to train the ner model using spacy. It works fine for CPU. But when I try executing it using GPU I'm getting the following error. Spacy version 2.1.4, CUDA version 10.1"

"I tried re-installing thinc but still I'm getting the error"

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import plac
import random
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
import json
spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for ent in annotations.get("entities"):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
```

"I'm getting the following error"

"CUDARuntimeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 `optimizer = nlp.begin_training()`

G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in `begin_training(self, get_gold_tuples, sgd, component_cfg, **cfg)`

```
    547             if self.vocab.vectors.data.shape[1] >= 1:
    548                 self.vocab.vectors.data = Model.ops.asarray(self.vocab.vectors.data)
--> 549         link_vectors_to_models(self.vocab)
    550         if self.vocab.vectors.data.shape[1]:
    551             cfg["pretrained_vectors"] = self.vocab.vectors.name
```

G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy_ml.py in `link_vectors_to_models(vocab)`

```
    297         else:
    298             word.rank = 0
--> 299     data = ops.asarray(vectors.data)
    300     # Set an entry here, so that vectors are accessed by StaticVectors
    301     # (unideal, I know)

ops.pyx in thinc.neural.ops.CupyOps.asarray()
```

G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\creation\from_data.py in `array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)`

```
     39 
     40     """
---> 41     return core.array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
     42 
     43
```

cupy\core\core.pyx in `cupy.core.core.array()`

cupy\core\core.pyx in `cupy.core.core.array()`

cupy\core\core.pyx in `cupy.core.core.ndarray.__init__()`

cupy\cuda\memory.pyx in `cupy.cuda.memory.alloc()`

cupy\cuda\memory.pyx in `cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()`

cupy\cuda\memory.pyx in `cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()`

cupy\cuda\device.pyx in `cupy.cuda.device.get_device_id()`

cupy\cuda\runtime.pyx in `cupy.cuda.runtime.getDevice()`

cupy\cuda\runtime.pyx in `cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status()`

CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorUnknown: unknown error"

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://spacy.io/usage/#gpu) to install spaCy with GPU support? And what spaCy version are you using?

Comment: Yes, It also true when I execute spacy.require_gpu(). Spacy version is 2.1.4

Comment: Could you try to use an existing model instead of creating a blank?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using existing model but still, I'm getting an error